# Angular5 ng-bootstrap, carousel indicators with dots

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the carousel indicators, it should be dots instead of lines and trying to change the color.

Please find below example of working carousel.

https://codesandbox.io/s/149o1qzr4l

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your styles.css

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width : 2px!important;
}
```

If you want to change colour of Dots to black for example then -

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width : 2px!important;
  background-color: black;
}
```

If you want to change the active slide/dot colour to yellow for example then -

```
.carousel-indicators .active {
  width : 2px!important;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Where I should add css for customization?

Comment: It didn't change the default css, guess not adding it at proper place, I added to css file of component

Comment: Did this help you @SahilKatia ?

Comment: Had to add /deep/ in front of the css in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @ [iBlehhz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10069848/iblehhz) says add /deep/ infront of the css. Maybe ::ng-deep also works. Worked for me.

Comment: /deep/ and ::ng-deep are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code.

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width : 20px!important;
  height: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  width : 20px!important;
  background-color: black;
  height: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width : 20px!important;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important
}
```